# How to customizing Learnpress plugin in Child theme in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, learnpress

We have customized the learnpress plugin but how do we apply the changes inside the "themes/Yoku-child" theme instead of "plugins/learnpress". Need your inputs.

Awaiting for your reply.

Thanks

Comment: Just move the plugin codes to functions.php and move the files to theme folder in child theme

Comment: Vel. Could you please explain more?

Comment: Just create a child theme and move the main plugin code to functions.php file in child theme